# iOS 7 SegmentControl Background Color

Tags: ios, uiview, background, uisegmentedcontrol, uicolor

Picture says it all (see arrows). Any way I can make sure the background is transparent? If I set the background to transparent on the UISegmentedControl it sets the button color to transparent too, but we want to avoid this.

[image]

Clarification: We want to keep the buttons white, but get rid of the white stuff in the corners. Setting background to white does this but then makes the buton background transparent too, which we don't want.

[image]

Update: Now looks as follows, after trying Astri's suggestion and setting corner radius to 5. Still, there is a white space on the right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After the clarification:

Try this:

```
yourSegmententControl.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
```

Make sure you import Quartz

Comment: this puts a space (the image) between buttons, but doesn't seem to solve the problem. I'm looking to modify the edges, not dividers.

Comment: Thanks for your example. the problem in our case is we don't have square corners (i.e. identical on all buttons as in your case), and thus lose the rounded corner effect (as in the original apple design).

Comment: Almost! Still a white space on the right. See update in question above.

Comment: Try to play with your segmented control width. Adding/removing couple of pixels seems to solve the problem

Comment: Trying this, but no luck..it seems to put that white margin in on the right no matter what.

Comment: setting the width to 289, you getting the same margin?

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same white space on the right problem when I explicitly set the width of the UISegmentedControl.

To fix it, do not set the width of the segmented control – just set the width of each segment instead.

```
// Determine your segment width
CGFloat segmentWidth = 50.0;

// Loop through the segments
for (NSInteger i=0; i<mySegmentedControl.numberOfSegments; i++) {

  // Set the width of each segment
  [mySegmentedControl setWidth:segmentWidth forSegmentAtIndex:i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The background colors of the views of the controlls are already transparent, so you need to set them too to whatever color you want, not just the background color of the view of the segmented controll. Keep in mind that the controlls have different configurations for their state.

Comment: If I set the background it to transparent, the buttons become transparent too, I want to keep those white.

Comment: So you need to change the buttons to white. Sorry, that would be an image, not a color. But an image of 1 pixel in the color you want will do. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UISegmentedControl.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012857-UISegmentedControl

Comment: Try this, but it seems to have no effect:

    UIImage *whiteImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"white.png"];

    [rating setBackgroundImage:whiteImage forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

Any thoughts?

Comment: More specifically, it seems to force the whole control's background to white (with no bevelled edges), and squeeze the last/first buttons out of proportion.